# SlideShowSettings.Run() freezes thread if presentation contains external media objects

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

I'm using the Office.Interop to control PowerPoint SlideShows, but I have problem with some presentations. If a presentation contains some external media objects, my app stops executing on the `SlideShowSettings.Run()` method and no exception is thrown (if it's called from the main thread, app freezes totally). Execution is then stopped until user closes the Microsoft Office Security Options dialog (image attached). Setting `ppApplication.DisplayAlerts` to `PpAlertLevel.ppAlertsNone;` doesn't help. Is there any setting to disable these dialogs? Or how to correctly handle this problem?

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a Windows security feature to ensure no harmful material can be streamed when viewing the PowerPoint..is there a way you can embed the external media files?

Comment: @Johan I'm not owner/author of presentations, so I can't change presentations before starts. App is used by clients to present their presentations

Comment: It's a PowerPoint "feature" that most PowerPoint users would happily remove if they could.  There's nothing you can do to change it programmatically; suggest to your clients that they put the PowerPoint and linked media files in a trusted folder.  That may help.